# Selenium TouchEvent does not work in device emulation

Tags: java, selenium

Need to use mobile device emulation on a desktop browser to automate testing.

If enable emulation via ChromeOptions (), the emulation of the touch screen does not work (the button responds to the cursor, etc.). That's why I use java.awt.Robot (F12 > Ctrl + Shift + M > iPad) to turn on device emulation. But touch doesn't work.

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;

//Set browser type and platform
DriverSettings.newSettings("https://staging.myev.com", DriverType.CHROME, EmulationType.MOBILE);
WebDriver driver = DriverSettings.getDriver();

driver.get("https://google.com");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='gb_x gb_Ub']"));
TouchActions touchActions = new TouchActions(driver);
touchActions.singleTap(element).perform();
```

The button is not pressed and there are no errors - "Process finished with exit code 0"

Maybe there is another way to enable mobile emulation or use TouchActions?

Comment: how do you enable the Mobile emulation? can you share your code?

Comment: I realize this might not be the quickest solution, but if all else fails, Appium might be a better fit.  It has its own set of touchactions separate from Selenium's, but it's not exactly a quick-and-dirty thing to implement.

Comment: I use import java.awt.Robot.
        
`       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F12);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F12);
        pause(500);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);`

Answer (score 0):

As per specifications from the official website: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation, to correctly use the mobile emulation with ChromeDriver you should use:

```
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();

mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Nexus 5");


ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)
```

*The emulated devices can also be made custom, for this you will need to declare a custom session storage with the stored custom devices properties. This needs to be done because if you dont declare a chrome session storage specifically, each time you will start a new test session, there will be created a temporary session with default settings.

Here you will find a useful lis of commands to start up the chromedriver:
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#user-data-dir